# How to Create a JSONArray using JSONObject with all values from a database table in java

Tags: java, json

I am fetching details from a database table which contains 3 rows in JAVA.
 I am using JSONarray and JSONObject as follows

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONObject mainjsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
```

The data from table is put to the jsonObject as follows for each one:

```
String qry="select * from details";
ResultSet res = select .executeQuery(qry);
while(res.next){

String Name=res.getString("name");
.
.

jsonObject.put("Name", Name);

.

.

ja.put(jsonObject);

}



mainjsonObject.put("PERSONAL DETAILS",ja);
```

i should get the output json as follows:

```
{
"PERSONAL DETAILS": [
    {
      " name": "abc",
      "age": "4",
      "gender": "F",
      "Place": "abc1"
    },
    {
      " name": "xyz",
      "age": "3",
      "gender": "M",
      "Place": "abc2"
    }


]

}
```

But am getting same values in both like below:

{

```
"PERSONAL DETAILS": [

    {

     " name": "abc",

     "age": "4",

     "gender": "F",

      "Place": "abc1"

    },

    {

   " name": "abc",

   "age": "4",

   "gender": "F",

   "Place": "abc1"

    }


]

}
```

Please help me with a solution. I need to get all the values from the tables as an array in JSON format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create new `JSONObject` in your loop otherwise the last record will be shown everywhere

```
while(res.next()){

    String Name=res.getString("name");
    jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    // ^^^^^^^^
    jsonObject.put("Name", res.getString(1));
    jsonObject.put("age", res.getString(2));
    jsonObject.put("gender", res.getString(3));
    jsonObject.put("Place", res.getString(4));
    ja.put(jsonObject);
 }
```

Comment: You beat me to it :p Except that there are some pieces of code missing from your example :)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @Pavneet_Singh. But can u pls cleary specify how to do it in the above one. Wat value to be given to the newly created JSONObject inside the loop

Comment: @Leeza as shown , get value from your `resultset` and put it inside `jsonObject` reference

Comment: @fge i guess you are talking about `next()`  , copied the code from OP to save some time :P

Comment: i am glad that we (me & @fge & SO) could help , happy coding

Comment: thanks a ton to all @pavneet and fge .I can tick only one answer ..thats y i ticked the one who responded first :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are reusing the same `JSONObject` over and over. And this is basically a `Map`.

What you need to do is create a *new* `JSONObject` instance and put it in the array for each iteration:

```
JSONObject obj;
while (rs.next()) {
    obj = new JSONObject();
    // fill in obj
    ja.put(obj);
}
```